# Code signing certificate error in Appium XCUITest

Tags: ios10, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I am trying UI automation of IOS 10 using Appium XCUITest.
On running script, it tries to build WebDriverAgent and fails at this point. I have added the provisioning profile and added the account in Xcode through the UI but not sure from where does XCUITest take the profiles while running or if we need to provide some information in desired capabilities.

```
info Xcode Testing failed:
info Xcode  Signing for "WebDriverAgentRunner" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
info Xcode  Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
info Xcode ** TEST FAILED **
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484957/appium-error-xcode-couldnt-find-a-provisioning-profile-matching-com-facebook-w/41628500#41628500 for the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix it as follows:

enters from the Finder to the following path:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent
```

open: `WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj`

```
select the targets:
WebDriverAgentLib
WebDriverAgentRunner
go to General tab -> Signing
and place the team
```

view image:
[solution appium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me9O6.png)

Answer (score 3):

This issue occurs for Appium 1.6.X, in order to fix the issue please follow the steps:

1. Go to your Appium folder and find appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj file or you can search for the file name.
2. Open the file using Xcode.
3. Select WebDriverAgentLib and In general tab select 'Automatically Manage Signing" and select an id in team dropdown (Ask your developement team to provide you the team id).
4. Now select the next WebDriverAgentRunner and do the same thing as you did for the WebDriverAgentLib.
5. In case you get some errors just go to the 'Build Settings' tab and change the "Product Bundle Identifier" from "com.facebook.WebDriverAgentLib" to "com.facebook.WebDriverAgentLibNew".
6. Come back to general tab and the errors should be fixed.
7. Now build both WebDriverAgentLib and WebDriverAgentRunner.
8. When you get the Build succeed message, run your test again.

Comment: Welcome! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I have edited the answer and added the steps instead of the link. I am sure it will be much more helpful.