# Appium error Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner'

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios

I have problem executing automation on real iOS device
system configuration:
appium 1.6.0
device iPhone 5c (ios 10.1)
xCode 8.2

the exception is:

```
[Xcode] 
Testing failed:
    No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner'.
    Code signing is required for product type 'UI Testing Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'
** TEST FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)

[XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
[XCUITest] Error: xcodebuild failed with code 65
    at SubProcess.<anonymous> (lib/webdriveragent.js:294:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at SubProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (lib/teen_process.js:191:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
 Error: xcodebuild failed with code 65
    at SubProcess.<anonymous> (lib/webdriveragent.js:294:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at SubProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (lib/teen_process.js:191:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
[debug] [XCUITest] Running ios real device reset flow
[debug] [XCUITest] Resetting simulator
[debug] [iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: xcodebuild failed with code 65
    at SubProcess.<anonymous> (lib/webdriveragent.js:294:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at SubProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (lib/teen_process.js:191:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
```

In xCode it seems that when I tried to sign WebDriverAgentRunner it failed to create provisioning profile and 
No profiles for 'com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner' were found

-----Edit-------

After trying to sign WebDriverAgentRunner with my free developer account I get 
the following error in xcode

[image: xCode error]

Please assist.

Comment: You can fix it as follows: [code signing certificate error in appium xcuitest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646676/code-signing-certificate-error-in-appium-xcuitest/39730091#39730091)

Comment: Hi! Did you find the way to fix this problem? I'd appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing the same issue While signing "WebDriverAgentRunner" as it does not have any Target Application to select the corresponding field shows "None".
I found this link while searching for the solution:
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7086

It says

> WebDriverAgent project has to be signed as well by the same developer signature as the main application under test.

Maybe it can help you, although I haven't tried it yet. But if you get any resolution, please share it here also.

Comment: Are you sure this is the issue?

Comment: @Tarun At that time with those versions that was the issue, now it depends on your current versions

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure you are signed in with developer account in Xcode.
2. Navidate to the folder `</path/to/appium>/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/`
3. Open the `WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj` project in Xcode.
4. Change the bunlder identifier for `WebDriverAgentLib, WebDriverAgentRunner from com.facebook.Webdriver** to your choice` so you can sign it with your provisioning profile.
5. Build the project for WebDriverAgentLib, WebDriverAgentRunner and IntegrationApp targets.
6. On the terminal, navigate to `</path/to/appium>/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/` and run `xcodebuild -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -destination 'id=<device udid>' test`
7. Last line in the logs should read `Listening on USB`.
8. Now run your appium scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `.ipa` file is not developer signed. All application artefacts must be signed by developer identity in iOS for Appium to use it.

You need to pass Appium `.ipa` file that is signed with valid Developer identity.

Comment: No. I tried to launch the settings app. I think that it has something to do with create profile or something like that

Comment: So you have valid `.ipa` file signed by Developer identity?

Comment: no. I just tried to automate settings app with appium. Do I need developer account?

Comment: Yes, it seem that you need it. At least my setup has the account. You need xcode to setup the automation profile or something like that on device before test launch and make sure that automation is enabled in settings.

Comment: I have default developer account (without paying 99$). Is this the account?

Comment: I do not know these specifics - developers helped me with those. Just try I guess.

Comment: can you check with them?

Answer (score 0):

Within the folder `~/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/`there is an xcode project called `WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj`

Open this and under `project -> general` there are 2 targets you need to add your profile to. Add it to the Targets labels `WebDriverAgentLib` and `WebDriverAgentRunner`

Now run the project on your device (I used a real device)

That is how I solved the issue when it occurred for me

Comment: The only reason why I think this could occur is if you do not have access to the WebDriverAgent project within your own directory. Perhaps perform a `chmod` operation on it?